# An error occurred when obtaining the request token after TBA verification of the netsuite website address. Node.js

Tags: node.js, authorization, netsuite

On the netsuite website, after TBA three-step authorization, an oauth_token and oauth_token_secret are returned.
I want to use node.js to initiate rest webservices request.
My process of obtaining token is as follows：

1. Create a signature base string
   The 'oauth_token' used here is returned by TBA three-step authorization.

```
  const method = "GET";
  const requestUrl = `https://example.suitetalk.api.netsuite.com/services/rest/record/v1/account?limit=5`;
  let params = new URLSearchParams();
  params.set("oauth_consumer_key", consumer_key);
  params.set("oauth_nonce", nonce);
  params.set("oauth_signature_method", "HMAC-SHA256");
  params.set("oauth_timestamp", time);
  params.set("oauth_token", oauth_token);
  params.set("oauth_version", "1.0");
  const parameters = params.toString();

  const signatureString = `${method}&${encodeURIComponent(requestUrl)}&${encodeURIComponent(parameters)}`;
```

2. Encrypted signature base string
   The 'oauth_token_secret' used here is returned by TBA three-step authorization.

```
const str1 = CryptoJS.HmacSHA256(signatureString, `${encodeURIComponent(consumer_secret)}&${encodeURIComponent(oauth_token_secret)}`);
  const str2 = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.stringify(str1);
  const signature = encodeURIComponent(str2);
```

3. Combined request headers Authorization

```
 const auth = `OAuth realm="${account_id}", oauth_token="${oauth_token}", oauth_consumer_key="${consumer_key}", oauth_nonce="${nonce}", oauth_timestamp="${time}", oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA256", oauth_version="1.0", oauth_signature="${signature}"`;
```

4. Make a request

```
  fetch({
    url: requestUrl,
    method,
    headers: {
      Authorization: auth,
    },
  });
```

But the error message always returned is Invalid login attempt.

Is there something wrong with my request header component?

The introduction of the authorization header in the official document is the same process as the signature generated by TBA, so I generated the signature and authorization header according to the TBA process. I tried not adding realm to the authorization header, but I still reported this error.

Comment: Have you checked the Login Audit Trail to see what specific reason the login was rejected?  If it's "invalid signature", then yes, that means there is an issue with the token generation, but sometimes the issue is a lack of permissions on the role you're using.

Comment: After I looked carefully in the View Login Audit Trail, I found that the difference between successful and failed records is that the successful record will show what the role is, and the failed record will not. So I guess it is related to role, but in the generated request header, there is no content related to role except oauth_token and oauth_token_secret returned by TBA. Regarding the issue of insufficient permissions you mentioned, this error will also be reported when I select the administrator identity during authorization and then call the interface.